# Can I grab HTML element by "Inner html" in Xamarin UI Test

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

Can I do this with some method, Query for example? 
I need to grab element which node from below represents and unique is onlu Inner Html content.

`<div class="headline">Check</div>`

I am creating UI test for mobile app with xamarin.

```
Query firstName => x => x.XPath("//input[@name='firstName']");
```

This way i was locating elements, but how can I get inner html?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way:

```
$x("(//*[contains(text(),'Dummy')])")
```

The syntax is for Chrome dev tools if anyone wonders.